# How to use Outer Join with date paramter situation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to join these three tables with outer join

Table1

```
 ID    NAME
 123   KING
 456   KONG
```

Table2:

```
ID   A_DATE    VALUE
123  9/1/2015  1000
123  8/1/2015  1100
123  7/1/2015  1200
456  8/1/2015  900
456  7/1/2015  800
```

Table3:

```
 Date
 9/1/2015
```

Query Using:

```
select t1.ID, t1.NAME, t2.A_Date t2.Value
from Table1 t1, Table2 t2
where  t1.ID = t2.ID(+)
and     t2.A_Date = (Select Date from Table3)
```

Current Results:

```
ID   NAME  A_DATE     VALUE
123  KING  9/1/2105   1000
```

This query only giving me common value.

Results Required:

```
ID   NAME  A_DATE     VALUE
123  KING  9/1/2105   1000
456  KONG   NULL      NULL
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? Don't use both tags, use the tag for the RDBMS you're actually using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write this using ANSI JOIN syntax, and put the constraint on the second table in the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.NAME, t2.A_Date, t2.Value
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t2.A_Date = (SELECT Date FROM Table3)
```

Using implicit joins, you need to test specifically for `NULL`.

```
select t1.ID, t1.NAME, t2.A_Date t2.Value
from Table1 t1, Table2 t2
where  t1.ID = t2.ID(+)
and t2.A_Date IS NULL OR t2.A_Date = (Select Date from Table3)
```